# Linking External dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dynamic-linking

I am working with Visual Studio 2012. I am externally "Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll". The project compiles and works fine when I run in debug mode. However gives me the following error message when I try to compile for release:

Warning 1   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b772ad94eb9ca604, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  WindowsPhoneNavigationTransitions

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: any other warning/error detail would you like to tell..

Comment: Are the project's Reference Paths set the same for debug and release configurations?

Comment: More errors include:
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'FlickGestureEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Yashwanth-PC\Desktop\WindowsPhoneNavigationTransitions\WindowsPhoneNavigationTransitions\Page3.xaml.cs 31 59 WindowsPhoneNavigationTransitions

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't know. Can you please tell me how to check that?

Comment: Assuming you're using C#, open the project's property page and click on the "Reference Paths' tab.  Check that it's set appropriately for both the Debug and Release configurations.

Comment: sorry..i dont have an option to do that. Configuration N/A and not editable

Comment: Mysterious problem.  You'll need to document in what directory the project is stored and *exactly* where the missing assembly is stored on your machine.